# Meteor and jQuery: .css does not work, .addClass("css-class") works

Tags: jquery, css, meteor

In a Meteor application, I have this on the client side:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Deps.autorun(function () {
        var p = Session.get("page");
        if(!!Session.get(p)) {
            _.map(pages, function(p) {
                $("." + p).children().remove();
            });
            $("." + p).append(Session.get(p));
            // Assign h2-link to h2's that contain an a
            // to customize their appearance in CSS
            $("a").parent("h2").addClass("h2-link");
        }
    });
});
```

The above code removes HTML from all dummy classes and appends a customized HTML snippet to the active one.

`$("a").parent("h2").addClass("h2-link");` applies a custom style to `h2`s that contain a link.

Now, having defined `h2-link` in CSS to be `.h2-link { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }` works perfectly.

Doing it directly via `$("a").parent("h2").css("border-bottom: 1px solid red;");` does not work.

*Why doesn't it work when I try to apply styles directly on the DOM?*

Does Meteor prohibit DOM-CSS-applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("a").parent("h2").css("border-bottom", "1px solid red")
```

Comment: Haha, that was an easy one. I was so confident that I knew the syntax ... thank you :-)